# Angular ng-maxlength marks field invalid when no explicit value is set and field contains any characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on dynamically creating a form with Angular (1.3b17). I'm storing my form's schema in an object, and including several properties that define my fields' behavior within that schema, for instance a field will have "type" (text, textarea, check, etc) and "maxlength" properties. I then set the angular attributes for my elements to the respective property for my object (ng-maxlength="field.maxlength" for instance).

I've noticed something a bit weird, and I wanted to see if this is working as intended. When the attribute is set, but no value is specified (ng-maxlength="") then $error is set to true immediately after typing anything, as it expects a maximum length of 0. Similarly, using an expression (ng-maxlength="field.maxlength") behaves in the same way if the property isn't set.

I've created a simple [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7M53bMvrkQuViYlmWBf2) so you can see what I'm referring to. I would personally expect there to be no maxlength checks if the value isn't set, even if the attribute is present.

```
<input id="txtName" ng-model="myval" type="text" name="name" ng-maxlength="" /><br />
{{myForm.name.$error}}
```

Or

```
<input id="txtName" ng-model="myval" type="text" name="name" ng-maxlength="someundefinedvalue" /><br />
{{myForm.name.$error}}
```

Of course, I could work around this by setting ng-maxlength to something large, but it doesn't seem ideal. Is there a reason for this behavior? Or could it be a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like as long as you define the directive on the form control [the validator is applied](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L2601) to it unfortunately. So, the answer to your question is, it's how it's always been, it might be considered a bug, but at this point it would be a breaking change and it's unlikely to be changed.

Comment: Bummer. Fair enough, I guess.